# JQuery Popup with User Control post back is setting control properties to null

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net

I have used user control with Teleric grid. it contains GridClientSelectColumn. I popup this user control using jquery. In this *"ok"* button I'd like to do a post back on a page and within the post back event to call a user control method that returns the selected column list.
But the selected item.selected is always false

How to solve this problem?

Comment: please post some code...

Comment: Do you have viewstate enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got a solution within the OK Button I use $(this).dialog("destroy"); It solved my problem Thank you all who try to help me.